# How to calculate the ratios of values to their sum?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have 3 BigDecimal values and I want to find 3 values that represent its ratio to their sum and those ratios should add up to 1. However, I'm running into the following error:

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("19000.0000");
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("31000.0000");
BigDecimal c = new BigDecimal("999901467.88");

BigDecimal sum = a.add(b).add(c); //999951467.8800

BigDecimal aRatio = a.divide(sum, 4, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP); //returns 0.0000
BigDecimal bRatio = b.divide(sum, 4, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP); //returns 0.0000
BigDecimal cRatio = c.divide(sum, 4, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP); //returns 0.9999

/** returns 0.9999 doesn't equal to 1! **/
BigDecimal totalRatio = aRatio.add(bRatio).add(cRatio);
```

As you can see the sum of the 3 ratios ***does not add up to 1***. I can change the scale from 4 to 5 and that will fix the issue. **However** I'm using the same code above to calculate other different numbers. So I'm trying to find a proper approach that ***will work for any X ratios with any numbers***.

Comment: I believe the left over decimal after ROUND_HALF_UP of first ratio should be added to next ratio before ROUND_HALF_UP of next ratio.  So, left over ratio (i.e. aRatio - ROUNDED_UP_ARatio) should be added to bRatio before calling its ROUND_HALF_UP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As soon as you use rounding, you effectively agree to have results that are not absolutely correct. So, if the goal is to have the sum of the ratios equal to 1, just do

```
BigDecimal aRatio = a.divide(sum, 4, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP); 
BigDecimal bRatio = b.divide(sum, 4, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP); 
BigDecimal cRatio = BigDecimal.ONE.subtract(aRatio.add(bRatio));
```

Comment: Do you use the same approach for X number of ratios?

Comment: I don't use that approach. You want to use it. But if that's what you want, then go for it.

Comment: Bad wording - but would that approach work for X ratios of any number? What if the last number is 0, then doing BigDecimal.ONE.subtract() on the last ratio wouldn't work, right?

Comment: It would work, but give an approximate value, i.e. a value that is close to 0. That's basically what you agree on when wanting the sum to be equal to 1. Let's take a simple example: 1, 1 and 1. The ratios are 0.3333 (rounded), 0.3333 (rounded), and 0.3333 (rounded). If you want the sum of the ratios to be equal to 1, then you need one of the ratios to be 0.3334. Is it less correct than 0.3333? Yes, of course. But that's because you want the sum to be equal to 1. You can't have your cake and eat it too.